# Make proxy use extended Ext.data.Operation

Tags: extjs, proxy, extjs4, datastore, extjs-mvc

I have extended `Ext.data.Operation` to implement a custom `commitRecords` method.

The `Ext.data.Operation` class is used for all communication between stores and their proxy.

The `commitRecords` method specifically is used to update the data in a data store according to data returned from a proxy writer.

I can't seem to get a grip on how to set up my proxies to use my extended version of `Ext.data.Operation`.

I've been rifling through the `Ext.data.*` package but can't seem to find where the `Ext.data.Operation` is created so I will know what class to tell to use this new extended `Ext.data.Operation` class with the custom `commitRecords` method.

Has anyone else extended this before, could give me some pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it, the `batch` method of `Ext.data.Proxy` is where an `Ext.data.Operation` object is created to send to the server.

I extended `Ext.data.proxy.Ajax` with a new `batch` method where I just switch out the `new Ext.data.Operation` for my own Operation class.

**EDIT**

Only because you asked DmitryB. The short story about why I had to implement my own commitRecords method is that I needed my data models "internalId" fields to match the actual database record ID field. I won't go into why exactly, it's too convoluted for me to express, but here's what I did:

How I understand it, the `commitRecords` method is fired as one of the last actions when calling `store.sync()` it automatically replaces the dirty records on the client side with the new server side records as long as you write your server side controller to return the new server record in the Ajax response, it does this whenever the sync request does an insert or update.

The official implementation of `commitRecords` tries to match this returned server record to the dirty client record by using the "internalId" field of the data model.

Obviously, I have no idea what the next incremental database ID is going to be for new records, so I cannot assign it on the client side as the ID before the record syncs with the database, therefore the server record will never match be able to match up against the dirty client record's internalId when commitRecords is called, i.e. the client record will not get the correct database ID, which I need.

So, because *all* of my writable data models for this app have a "create_time" field I decided to make the commitRecords method match the server records with the client records using the "create_time" field instead of "internalId".

Here is the extended Ext.data.Operation class, where I did this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.ux.QueryOperation', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Operation',

    /** 
     * Use the date_created timestamp if we cant match to an ID.
     * This allows client records that did not previously exist on the server
     * to be updated with the correct server ID and data
     * NB: All implementing data models require a "date_created" field.
     */
    commitRecords: function (serverRecords) {
        var me = this,
            mc, index, clientRecords, serverRec, clientRec;
        if (!me.actionSkipSyncRe.test(me.action)) {
            clientRecords = me.records;
            if (clientRecords && clientRecords.length) {
                if (clientRecords.length > 1) {
                    mc = new Ext.util.MixedCollection();
                    mc.addAll(serverRecords);
                    Ext.each(clientRecords, function(clientRec) {
                        serverRec = mc.findBy(function(record) {
                            var clientId = clientRec.getId(),
                                clientTime = clientRec.get('date_created').getTime(),
                                serverTime = record.get('date_created').getTime();
                                if(clientId && record.getId() === clientId) {
                                    return true;
                                }
                                // timestamp can be within 2ms of record
                                // (it seems to change slightly in serialization)
                                return (clientTime > serverTime - 2 && clientTime < serverTime + 2);
                        });
                        me.updateClientRecord(clientRec, serverRec);
                    });
                } else {
                    clientRec = clientRecords[0];
                    serverRec = serverRecords[0];
                    me.updateClientRecord(clientRec, serverRec);
                }
                if (me.actionCommitRecordsRe.test(me.action)) {
                    for (index = clientRecords.length; index--; ) {
                        clientRecords[index].commit();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

});
```

As I mentioned in the answer, I found that I had to extend proxy to make use of my new Operation class. The only thing I extended was the `batch` method, replacing only two lines in the method which said `new Ext.data.Operation` to now say `new MyApp.ux.QueryOperation` (my new Operation class above). This then called my own commitRecords method when a response came back from the server. I also gave the extended proxy an alias "proxy.query" so that I could tell my stores to use it like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: [
        'ST.ux.QueryProxy',
    ],
    title: 'Student',
    model: 'MyApp.model.MyModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'query',
        // ... ^^^^^ uses my QueryProxy now
        // other configs...
    }
});
```

(If it seems like I am going about this wrong way or missed something in the docs, please let me know. I would be happier with a built in method of achieving this functionality.)

Comment: good find. don't be shy and share some code :) who knows, maybe one day it will be useful.

Comment: @DmitryB OK, I explained myself

Comment: I think your use case is similar to what many face. In my experience if your ID attribute on your model is of type 'int' the default proxy does the right thing when running sync(). I used to have my ID property a string and that caused sync to fail commit operation as you described. Essentially my grid records would always show 'dirty' flags even though they have been synced to server.